# can we give <div> within <li>

Tags: html, tags, layer, html-lists

can we give div tag within un order list tag.............. it will be in this format

```
<li><div>blablabla</div></li>
```

Is it Possible

Comment: By "Is it Possible" what do you mean?

Comment: Related question [Alternatives to illegal <br> or <p> within <li> tags> on a hover?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427721/alternatives-to-illegal-br-or-p-within-li-tags-on-a-hover)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are a lot of people that say a division inside a list item is incorrect, but according to the W3C validator it is perfectly fine. You'll never catch me putting divisions inside a list item though. Lists are too malformed to be putting additional block-level elements inside them.

Answer (score 5):

Syntactically, if you are unsure about the nesting of elements, there are free tools that will tell you what, if anything, is wrong. For example:

http://validator.w3.org/

Whether or not it is semantically correct is another story. You might be suffering of [divitis](http://www.google.com/search?q=divitis).

Answer (score 1):

yes, but you need the < ol > tag also wrapping all the < li > tags that can have whatever you want inside them

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're making a horizontal nav bar.  If my assumption is correct, you don't need a `<div>` inside `<li>`.  You can use `display:inline;` to get `<li>` to behave some what like `<div>`.