# I can't get my todo list to work right

Tags: javascript, html

For some reason I can't get my todo list to work. First, I have a global variable named "list" which stores: `document.getElementById('GList');` "Glist" is the id of an ordered list element I have. Then, I have a textarea with an id named "goal" and a function called `AddGoal()`. As you will see below, the first thing the function does is get the value of the textarea with the id named "goal" and stores it into a variable also named "goal". Another variable is created called "entry" which stores a created li element like this `var entry = document.createElement('li');` This variable "entry" is also given attributes using `entry.setAttribute`. It's given a class and a class name "MyList". What happens with the code below is, I type in text to the textarea, the text is added to my list and everything is fine until I try to add another item to my list. Once I add another item, it replaces the first item and adds additional li elements but all containing the same replacing text. I would appreciate your help.

This last part of the function finally adds the text that was typed in the textarea to my ordered list and `li` element with the class "MyList".

```
entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(goal));
list.appendChild(entry);
```

This is my attempt at getting the li element with the class "MyList" and making it's innerHTML a `p` element with a class that will add the image I want to it plus a `div` with a class name "goalTxt" wrapping the variable goal which contains the text from the `textarea` element and the reason I'm wrapping the goal variable with this `div` with a class is so I can make sure it will always be in a certain position with CSS.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('MyList')[0].innerHTML = "<p class='bulletp'></p>" + "   <div class='goalTxt'>" + goal + "</div>";
```

Here's the full code:

```
<style>
.bulletp {
    position:relative;
    top:-2px;
    left:5px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 20px;
    background-image:url('images/point_03.png');
}
</style>
<ol id="GList"></ol>
<textarea id="goal"></textarea> 
<script>
var list = document.getElementById('GList');

function AddGoal() {
    var goal = document.getElementById('goal').value;
    var entry = document.createElement('li');
    entry.setAttribute("class", "MyList");
    entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(goal));
    list.appendChild(entry);
    document.getElementsByClassName('MyList')[0].innerHTML = "<p class='bulletp'></p>" +
        "<div class='goalTxt'>" + goal + "</div>";
}
</script>
<input type='button' onclick='AddGoal()' value='Submit' />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are updating using `getElementsByClassName('MyList')[0].innerHTML`. The `[0]` means it will always update the first element with `class='MyList'` and hence your first `li` value is also getting updated.

You don't need that line at all. Just remove it. Here is a sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/3swKe/). I have commented out that entire line.

**EDIT:** Alternately, if you are looking to achieve the below structure for all your `li`, use this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/3swKe/1/).

**Expected Structure:**

```
<li class="MyList">
    <p class="bulletp"></p><div class="goalTxt">abcd</div>
</li>
```

**Corresponding Code:**

```
function AddGoal() {
    var goal = document.getElementById('goal').value;
    var entry = document.createElement('li');
    entry.setAttribute("class", "MyList");

    var bulletp = document.createElement('p'); // to add <p> tag
    bulletp.setAttribute("class", "bulletp");
    entry.appendChild(bulletp);

    var goalTxt = document.createElement('div'); // to add <div> tag
    goalTxt.setAttribute("class", "goalTxt");
    goalTxt.appendChild(document.createTextNode(goal));

    entry.appendChild(goalTxt);
    list.appendChild(entry);
   //console.log(list.innerHTML);

}
```

**Note:** I would strongly recommend not using `<p>` or `<div>` tags inside a `<li>` tag.

Comment: Thanks a lot Harry. My I also ask why you recommend not using <p> or <div> tags inside an <li> tag?

Comment: As mentioned by animuson in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011934/can-we-give-div-within-li) post, it validates fine with W3C validator. It is more a personal preference.