# Is <p> semantically correct within an <li> element

Tags: html

I'm marking up a series of knowledge base how-to type articles which have a series of steps and associated screenshots. In the past I have always wrapped text within a list item within paragraph tags but I'm wondering if this is semantically correct in this case or if I should be using a heading tag (or even nothing). I'm tempted to mark it up as follows:

```
<ol class="kbarticle">
        <li>
            <p>Download the Windows client software <a href="">here</a>.</p>
            <a href="#screenshot1"><img src="screen1.jpg" alt="Step 1" /></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>Double click the downloaded file and click "Next" to continue.</p>
            <a href="#screenshot2"><img src="screen2.jpg" alt="Step 2" /></a>
        </li>
<ol>
```

Additionally, if there are any HTML5 elements which would be more semantically correct, I'd love to know.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here’s one way you could mark it up using `<figure>`:

```
<ol class="kbarticle">
  <li>
    <figure>
      <a href="#screenshot1"><img src="screen1.jpg" alt="Step 1"></a>
      <figcaption>
        Download the Windows client software <a href="">here</a>.
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <a href="#screenshot2"><img src="screen2.jpg" alt="Step 2"></a>
      <figcaption>
        Double click the downloaded file and click "Next" to continue.
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I think this is bad, due by definition <FIGURE> is an element which can be removed of the page WITHOUT affecting the flow of the document. But if you would remove that figure your list will be without any content.

Comment: this is not an answer to the question

Answer (score 51):

Yes, it's valid. LI is defined as

```
<!ELEMENT LI - O (%flow;)*             -- list item -->
```

and `%flow` is defined as

```
<!ENTITY % flow "%block; | %inline;">
```

and `%block` naturally contains P, as it's a block level element.

Comment: Heads-up: The question is on semantic correctness, not structural correctness.

Answer (score 10):

I'd say that more often than not, the `<p>` tags are superfluous and the `<li>` tags alone are sufficient, but it's a fine call, and I don't think what you're doing is really harmful.

Answer (score 7):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427721/alternatives-to-illegal-br-or-p-within-li-tags-on-a-hover/427743#427743), `li`'s can contain block or inline elements (from the HTML4 spec).

Comment: Heads-up: The question is on semantic correctness, not structural correctness.