# HTML - Is it semantically correct to use multiple <p> tags and nest <ul> inside <li></li>?

Tags: html, semantic-markup, semantic-html

I need to code the following text in HTML:

1. Data:

   We collect...

   - a
   - b
2. Aditional data:

   We collect...

   - c
   - d

Is it correct to do the following in html?

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>Data:</p>
    <p>We collect...</p>
    <ul>
      <li>a</li>
      <li>b</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>
    ...
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is <p> semantically correct within an <li> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660575/is-p-semantically-correct-within-an-li-element)

Comment: It doesnt talk about ul nesting

Comment: Almost every submenu is a `ul` nested in an `li`...

Answer (score 1):

It's valid HTML, but without knowing more about your content, it's hard to determine if it's semantically correct. It seems like it may be more correct in this instance to use sections with headings instead:

```
<section>
  <h2>Data</h2>
  <p>We collect...</p>
  <ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
  </ul>
</section>
<section>
  <h2>Additional Data</h2>
  <p>We collect...</p>
  <ul>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```