# indent paragraphs in roman list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I need a list with lower-roman indexes, the content of the list should be indented , the indexes should have parentheses (ii)

**E.g.:**

```
(i)     hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello
        hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello
        hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello

(ii)    world world world world world world world world world
        world world world world world world world world world
        world world world world world world world world world

(iii)   abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde
        abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde
        abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde


finished with the list..
blablah .....
```

here is what I tried:

```css
li {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

ol.roman {
  text-align: justify;
  list-style-position: inside;
  counter-reset: list;
}

ol.roman>li {
  list-style: none;
}

ol.roman>li:before {
  padding-right: 20px;
  content: "(" counter(list, lower-roman) ") ";
  counter-increment: list;
}
```

```html
<ol class="roman">
  <li>
    hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello
  </li>
  <li>
    world world wworld world world world world world world world world world world world world world world world world world world world world world world world world world world world world world
  </li>
  <li>abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde</li>
</ol>
<p>finished with the list..</p>
```

but it does not indent the whole paragraph, how can I achieve the above?

Comment: You cannot have a `<br />` as a sibling to `<li>` and there's no `</br>`!

Comment: how do I keep a line between each item in the list?

Comment: Use CSS: `li {margin-bottom: 15px;}`. Also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/427721

Comment: thanks! I edit my question

Comment: great it works! Ill accept it as soon as I can (8 minutes)

Comment: Sure man... Will wait.

Comment: Is there anything else I could help you with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add all my comments previously.

1. You cannot have a `<br />` as a sibling to `<li>`!
2. There's no `</br>`!
3. Use absolute and relative positioning.

```css
ol.roman {
  text-align: justify;
  list-style-position: inside;
  counter-reset: list;
}

ol.roman > li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

ol.roman > li:before {
  content: "(" counter(list, lower-roman) ") ";
  counter-increment: list;
  position: absolute;
  left: -35px;
  text-align: right;
  display: block;
  width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<ol  class="roman">
  <li>hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello</li>
  <li>world world wworld world world world world world world world world world world world world world world world world world world world world world world world world world world world world world</li>
  <li>abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde</li>
</ol>
<p>finished with the list..</p>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]